# Python appium webdriver.Remote errors with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Tags: python, appium, bluestacks

after setting up appium inspector, I was able to access to my BlueStack device from inspector

{
"platformName": "Android",
"appium:deviceName": "localhost:5555",
"appium:platformVersion": "7",
"appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages": "true",
"appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
}

but accessing the device from python script it gives me error with

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

```
capabilities = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    automationName='uiautomator2',
    platformVersion='7',
    deviceName='localhost:5555',
    # appPackage='com.android.settings',
    # appActivity='.Settings',
    # language='en',
    # locale='US'
)

appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, capabilities)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

    def test_find_battery(self) -> None:
        el = self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//*[@text="Battery"]')
        el.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

what could I do to fix the issue?
Thanks a head for the responses

fyi: device name -
adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:OnePlus5 model:ONEPLUS_A5000 device:OnePlus5 transport_id:1
localhost:5555         device product:OnePlus5 model:ONEPLUS_A5000 device:OnePlus5 transport_id:3

tried from inspector, follow the documentation but failed

Comment: Please provide the whole stack trace and not only the one line with the error. Since you do not call the attribute yourself, it's hard to tell and what part your code fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the new version of appium version changed its function signature

Try this:

```
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        options = UiAutomator2Options()
        options.load_capabilities(capabilities)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! 
I know it was a simple thing but was just hard block since I was new to this.